# Passing controls between top levels in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a tkinter learner. I am trying to pass control between different top levels. I have a root window with a button. Button press will open a toplevel ( I named as level_1). There are two buttons and field to enter two integers. Submit button and cancel button. Submit is working fine. ´What I am trying to achieve is, pressing cancel button should bring another top level (I named as level_2) with two buttons, yes and two. pressing yes should close level_1 and level_2. Pressing No, should close just level_2. My doubt is how to pass this level names between functions? Shall I use labda?

```
from tkinter import *
root= Tk()
root.geometry('600x400')
sum_var= StringVar()

def entry_Fn():
    level_1 = Toplevel(root)
    Label( level_1, text = "level one- Enter two integers").pack()
    entry_1 = Entry(level_1)
    entry_1.pack()
    entry_2 = Entry(level_1)
    entry_2.pack()
    def submitBtn():
        val_1= entry_1.get()
        val_2= entry_2.get()
        sum_var.set(int(val_1)+ int(val_2))
        level_1.destroy()
    def cancelEntry():
        level_2 = Toplevel(level_1) #is it right? root or level_1?
        Label( level_2, text = "level two- Cancel data entry").pack()
        Button(level_2, text= "Yes", command=cancelFn).pack()
        Button(level_2, text= "No", command=backEntryFn).pack()
  #function for canceling   
    def cancelFn():
        level_2.destroy() 
        level_1.destroy()

    def backEntryFn():
        level_2.destroy()

    Button(level_1, text= "submit", command=submitBtn).pack()
    Button(level_1, text= "Cancel", command=cancelEntry).pack()

Label(root, text = "Main window").pack()
Button(root, text= "To enter Data", command= entry_Fn).pack()
sum = Label(root, textvariable = sum_var)
sum.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

## error when pressed No in level_2

level_2.destroy()
NameError: name 'level_2' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need to use `lambda` for this. All you need to do is to indent your functions:

```
def cancelEntry():
    level_2 = Toplevel(level_1)  # is it right? root or level_1?
    Label(level_2, text="level two- Cancel data entry").pack()

# function for canceling
    def cancelFn():
        level_2.destroy()
        level_1.destroy()

    def backEntryFn():
        level_2.destroy()

    Button(level_2, text="Yes", command=cancelFn).pack()
    Button(level_2, text="No", command=backEntryFn).pack()
```

But a more organized way is to create a class and access difference instances of your `Toplevel` as attributes:

```
from tkinter import *

root= Tk()
root.geometry('600x400')
sum_var= StringVar()

class Level1(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self,master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        Label(self, text = f"level one - Enter two integers").pack()
        self.entry_1 = Entry(self)
        self.entry_1.pack()
        self.entry_2 = Entry(self)
        self.entry_2.pack()
        Button(self, text="submit", command=self.submitBtn).pack()
        Button(self, text="cancel", command=self.cancelEntry).pack()

    def submitBtn(self):
        val_1= self.entry_1.get()
        val_2= self.entry_2.get()
        sum_var.set(int(val_1)+ int(val_2))
        self.destroy()

    def cancelEntry(self):
        self.level_2 = Toplevel()
        Label(self.level_2, text = "level two- Cancel data entry").pack()
        Button(self.level_2, text= "Yes", command=self.cancelFn).pack()
        Button(self.level_2, text= "No", command=self.backEntryFn).pack()

    def cancelFn(self):
        self.level_2.destroy()
        self.destroy()

    def backEntryFn(self):
        self.level_2.destroy()

Label(root, text = "Main window").pack()
Button(root, text= "To enter Data", command=Level1).pack()
s = Label(root, textvariable = sum_var)
s.pack()
root.mainloop()
```